# Dynamic data wont change in flask

Tags: python, json, api, flask, pymysql

I'm trying to make an API in flask, but when I load up the API and then change the data in the database and reload the page the data doesn't change unless I restart the program. How do I make it so when the program is running and I change the data in the database I'll see it when I refresh the API in the browser? Thanks in Advance.

Here's the code:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request 
import pymysql.cursors

connection = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
user='root',
password='myroot',
db='test',
charset='utf8mb4',
cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def test():
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        connection.connect()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM importantData"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
    return jsonify(result)

@app.route('/locations', methods=['GET'])
def test1():
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        connection.connect()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM locations"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
    return jsonify(result)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(port=8080)
```

EDIT:
The solution was that I had to open the database connection in every route function, edited the code so now it works as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that I had to open the database connection in every route function, edited the code so now it works as it's supposed to

Answer (score 0):

I have never used pymysql, and your code looks fine except that part:

```
result = cursor.fetchone()
```

Why `fetchone()` when you are clearly `select *` selecting everything? What do you mean by `I change data in database`, did you change a row, or did you insert a new row?

In anycase, looks like you are selecting only the first row with `fetchone()`, so even if you changed something else, or if you added a new row, you will never see the new modifications

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out I currently changed it to fetchall but the problem I'm encountering is while the API is live, if I change the data and refresh the API on the browser the data doesn't, instead it's stuck on the previous values

Comment: you still didn't answer my question.. Have you changed the 1st row, and you still see the old version of it, or have you added new rows, and they do not appear even after you have changed `fetchone()` to `fetchall()` ?

Comment: both, I changed the 1st row and added a 2nd one but the new data doesn't show up